# Reports: How do I report on the first activity created for a lead?

Tags: reporting

I would like to create a report that shows me when I had the first phone call with a lead. So, when we have a new lead, we have a call with them and record this using the "add call" feature. we might then have a number of follow up calls. However, I want to write a report that shows me the date of the very first call.

Is this possible, or would it be a better solution to have a formula field or something on lead that is populated when the first call has been placed?

Tia.

Answer (score 1):

@Lily, I second what Jenny B recommended, in that the best approach may be to customize Salesforce to do some kind of a roll-up to determine First Activity Date. If you want to avoid writing actual code to do this, I think you can adapt what I wrote in a [blog post](http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2014/05/last-event-or-task-date-vs-last.html) to leverage Andy Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Roll-Up Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) app to find the First Activity Date.

Essentially Andy's app is a free version of the [Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) app.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be an easy way to accomplish this in reports, there is an idea out on the ideaexchange [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lB1fAAE), please go vote it up. Most questions I've found on this has resulted in suggesting a trigger to set a field on the lead record called "First Activity Date", like this one [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50435/having-trouble-writing-my-first-trigger-that-populates-a-lead-field-based-off-of) and this one [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55246/formula-question-record-a-date-of-first-activity-on-contact-object). I haven't used the process builder yet, but I'm guessing you could use that or flow to update the lead record after the first activity is created.
The only report function I could see doing is a join report with leads and activities and sort the activity dates ascending but that would give you all activities, another option would be to create a custom report "leads with activities" but again that would give you all the activities.